# JFileChooser file type filtering not working

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I'm trying to filter file types in my `JFileChooser` like this;

```
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
fc.setDialogTitle(langManager.getText("programwidget.urlbutton.fd.text"));
fc.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter(null, "ico", "png", "gif"));
```

But when I launch it, I can still choose another file types, so it's not working as I expected.

Can someone please tell me what I'm missing here?

Comment: Seems to work okay for me.  Make sure that the filter is selected, probably giving it a name would help

Comment: See also [ImageIO.getReaderFileSuffixes()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#getReaderFileSuffixes--). It's better than guessing what file types are supported for reading images.